# «Быть может» — вводная конструкция?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, поэзия, выбор-варианта

Есть ли какой-то действенный способ определить, является ли "быть может" вводной конструкцией? Убрать из предложения ее не всегда является работающим и практичным методом.

> Бил с правотой уверенной, весомой,
> и, взмокший, раскрасневшийся, весёлый,
> он крикнул мне: «Добавь и ты, малыш!»
>
> Не помню, сколько их, галдевших, било.
> **Быть может**(?) сто, **быть может**(?) больше было,
> но я, мальчишка, плакал от стыда.
> И если сотня, воя оголтело,
> кого-то бьёт, — пусть даже и за дело! —
> сто первым я не буду никогда!

Убрать "быть может" нельзя, а переделывать предложение — каким образом?
Заменить на "возможно"? Опять же это не универсальный способ.
Разве в этом стихе нельзя расставить запятые в данном порядке: "Быть может сто, быть может, больше было..."?

Comment: Я тоже так думаю. "Быть может сто, быть может, больше было...". Первое "быть может" - сказуемое, а второе - вводное. Способ есть: если это сказуемое, тогда не вводное. Если это не сказуемое, тогда вводное.

Comment: @user190920 Так себе: *Может быть число сто.* И параллелизм нужен: *Может быть он, может быть, она* — звучит неоднородно, не по-нормальному. В стихе ритм важен, а такое его сбивает.

Comment: По ходу, есть способ. Когда вводное, ударение падает на "может".

Answer (score 3):

1. Это стихотворение **Е. Евтушенко** [Картинка детства.](https://rupoem.ru/evtushenko/rabotaya-loktyami-my.aspx)

В печатном варианте обособлены **оба вводных слова**. Остается доказать, что «быть может» является вводным сочетанием, а не сказуемым, но как это сделать?

2. **Убрать из предложения или переставить**? Это школьный способ: далеко не каждое вводное слово можно так проверить, если его семантика и позиция важны для этого предложения. Такой способ применяется в **частных случаях**, например для проверки структуры предложений с союзом А. Но и что же тогда делать?
3. Думаю, что надо провести **структурно-грамматический анализ**. Что мы будем проверять? Значение **предположения** может выражать сказуемое, а не только вводное слово.

Вся фраза имеет такой **смысл**: *Сколько их било? Быть может(,) их было сто,  быть может(,) их было больше*. В таком варианте глагол «быть» повторяется в **обеих частях**, а это некорректно. Да и все предложение без обособления (***быть может сто***) выглядит странно.

К тому же нарушается **симметричность** фразы, так что замена вводного слова сказуемым выглядит необоснованно. Ну и в общем случае вмешиваться в структуру **стихотворного текста** особенно нежелательно, так как инверсия слов и расстановка пауз в нем зависят от **ритмики** стиха.

4. Вот только **запятых в одной строке много** (поэтому неясно прочитывается текст), но вводные слова допускается обособлять **тире.** Тогда получится так:

*Не помню, сколько их, галдевших, било.*

***Быть может — сто, быть может — больше было***,

*но я, мальчишка, плакал от стыда.*

**Примечание**. Два тире использованы для обозначения **параллельности** конструкции. Подобное оформление есть у Розенталя в теме неполных и эллиптических предложений (пункт 2): *Здесь — овраги, дальше — степи.* http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Comment: Но нельзя же тире свободно использовать. У Розенталя есть три пункта.

Comment: Только три? Тогда добавьте четвертый (причину я указала).

Comment: Понимаю вашу точку зрения. Но нет же графического тире (для чёткого внешнего вида предложения). Другое дело, если бы была двусмысленность из-за запятых. Здесь получается, что варианты интонационно подчёркиваются.

Comment: Понимаю. Но это больше авторская пунктуация. В правилах такого нет. Потому что это не то, как делает большинство. Это же не рисование. Но интонационное тире не только даёт больше паузу, оно ещё указывает, что дальше важная информация, которую хочется подчеркнуть.

Comment: Извините, но я все уже сказала, больше добавить нечего.

Comment: Увы, графическое тире — это не норма. Авторская пунктуация — это когда правилами объяснить нельзя, но можно объяснить своей логикой. А разве нельзя повторять глагол? Иногда без этого никак. У нас же нет местоимений для замены глагола.