# Есть ли ошибка в видовременной соотнесённости?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, однородные-члены

Нет ли ошибки в видовременной соотнесённости сказуемых в этом предложении?

*Слово может быть употреблено неуместно или прозвучать фальшиво.*

Имею в виду **может быть употреблено** и **может прозвучать**.

Comment: Слово может 'быть употреблено неуместно' или (слово может) прозвучать фальшиво. Однородные обстоятельства. Нет ошибки. Свеча может гореть или погаснуть.

Comment: Стилистически это так себе. Связь с "может" почти не улавливается из-за неоднородности.

Comment: @oleedd а если запятую поставить?

Comment: @Буратино Запятая (пауза) ещё больше от "может" отдаляет.

Comment: @oleedd Ну а вот это: Мы строили, строили и наконец построили!

Comment: @Буратино Ну это и рядом не стояло. Здесь всё норм. При чём здесь оно?

Comment: @oleedd тогда так: Слово может быть употреблено неуместно, и потому звучать фальшиво. То есть : если слово употреблено неуместно, оно звучит фальшиво. А со свечой норм или нет: "Свеча может гореть, или погаснуть," - запятая нужна?

Comment: @Буратино Это мне больше нравится. Поскольку нет "или" (с ним не всё гладко), "потому" будто связка и нет приставки (это удачнее). Можно без запятой.

Comment: @oleedd Или такое: пламя может быть погасло, или может гореть.

Comment: @Буратино Со свечой не норм из-за другого. Зачем "может"? Она или горит, или не горит. Ну и однородности нет (продолжительное действие и моментное), если "погаснуть", то "зажечься". Во втором примере "может быть" вводное. Похожий пример: *Он, наверное, ушёл или остался.* Такие вводные относят не к одному слову, а ко всему простому предложению.

Comment: Недавно был вопрос про такое: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473782

Comment: @oleedd может тут - это предположение, а не утверждение или вводное. Свеча вероятно горит, или уже погасла.

Comment: @oleedd в общем я добавил ответ, со своим вариантом исправления, но я могу наврать 200%, так что, если не сложно, проверь, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Буратино Тогда это вводное, а не сказуемое. Но не говорят так. Говорят так: *Свеча, может, горит, а может, она уже погасла.* Но первое "может" уже намекает, что может быть иначе. Не ляпалиссиада?

Answer (score 1):

*Слово **может быть употреблено** неуместно или **прозвучать** фальшиво.*

Как уже было сказано, грамматика нормальная, но есть проблемы с стилем (не просматривается ясно отнесенность "может" к "быть употреблено" и "прозвучать".

Но все варианты правок не показались мне удачными, поэтому лучше отказаться от  причастной формы глагола "употребить" и сделать замену, например:

*Слово **может показаться** неуместным или **прозвучать** фальшиво.*

**Примечание.** Вообще говоря, в стилистике рекомендуется по возможности пользоваться глаголами, а не причастными формами.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, дело не во видовременном, а в согласованности глаголов. Неудачно использованы союз "или" и приставка "про-".

Возможные варианты:

*слово может быть употреблено не уместно и потому звучать фальшиво*;

*слово может быть употреблено не уместно — и звучать фальшиво*.

Или по-другому:

*если слово употреблено не уместно, оно звучит фальшиво*;

*слово звучит фальшиво по причине, что употреблено оно не уместно*.

"Не уместно" тут раздельно, так как отрицание уместности.

Comment: Нормально. "Вроде" — это не водное.

Comment: Хм, насчёт приставки "про-": вроде бы та же проблема, что в примере про свечу.

Comment: @oleedd насчет про-, возникает путаница, что считать причиной: то что прозвучало или то что употреблено. Звучать без про- - что-то более постоянное и нейтральное, постоянный эффект, уходит в подчинение "употреблено" и не выступает причиной.

Comment: @oleedd мне кажется нужно тире)

Слово может быть употреблено не уместно - и звучать фальшиво. Сказать - одно. Написать - тот еще геморрой)

Comment: А зачем здесь причина? Одновременные действия. Только одно постоянное (*быть*), а другое моментное (из-за приставки).

Comment: *В общем, дело не во временном соотнесении* — "видовременной" в вопросе как раз в тему: https://mostitsky_universal.academic.ru/1117/видовременной

Comment: Чтобы отображалось с новой строки, два пробела перед "↵". Это самый простой способ. А то абзацы постоянно.